# Receive a specific data from fire-base real time database using android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I develop an android application for students attendance according to their seat numbers. If the student entered his seat number, it will be stored into real time database in fire-base. 
Now, what I need to do is to retrieve the empty seat numbers to a list view according to students' information. for example: database has 50 seat numbers entered, but seat number (25) is not in the database then it will be retrieved to the list view. 
In general how can I do that with fire-base real time database? 
[This is how database looks like for one student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKUqu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to mark seat empty in your db to later only fetch the empty seats. In current situation there is no way to put a query which can retrieve data only for absent students.
Your screenshot is limited so I suggest this structure.

```
{lectureId}/
   seatNumber: {
      isEmpty: boolean,
      .... your other data
   }
```

Then you will use `orderByChild("isEmpty").equalTo(false);`

And for querying a set of data from realtime database, have a look at the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I have another question how can I mark `isEmpty: boolean` for each student who entered his seat number?

Comment: what info you have before update the boolean? Do you have seat number or student id or both ?

Comment: I have both of them

Comment: `db.ref('lectures').child('YOUR_LECT_ID').child("SEAT_NUMBER").child('isEmpty').set(true/false)` this is how its done in javascript you can easily convert it to android.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a boolean if student is present (present = true). 
put this variabble in te object 
then you can run a loop on datasnashot for

```
i < noOfSeats
```

and show in te ListView with a condition

```
if (!present){
   showInList();
}
```